# How to extract a zip archive?

Tags: doom, install

I'm making some changes to [emacs-emojify](https://github.com/iqbalansari/emacs-emojify) in my personal confgs to update the emojis to the latest version.

So far I downloaded the zip.

```
(url-copy-file "https://github.com/hfg-gmuend/openmoji/releases/latest/download/openmoji-72x72-color.zip"
                 (concat (locate-user-emacs-file "emojis") "/openmoji-72x72-color-latest.zip"))
```

How do I extract `~/.emacs.d/.local/etc/emojis/openmoji-72x72-color-latest.zip` in the same directory?

I'm using Doom Emacs.

```
(use-package! emojify
  :config
  (url-copy-file "https://github.com/hfg-gmuend/openmoji/releases/latest/download/openmoji-72x72-color.zip"
                 (concat (locate-user-emacs-file "emojis") "/openmoji-72x72-color-latest.zip"))
  ;;extract
  (setq  emojify-emoji-set "openmoji-72x72-color-latest"))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You can use `shell-command` to extract zip file through terminal commands.